# How does people make ASP.NET page in URL with html file name?

Tags: asp.net

I seen an ASP.NET application, in the URL is saying:

http://xxxxxxxxx/FILENAME.html?xxxx=xxx

How come it is html file? But not aspx file? How did they do it?

I heard from my manager that's an ASP.NET project he outsourced.

Sometime I seen people with their web page is ended in **.html** too, but obviously that is generated dynamically...

Comment: In .NET, you don't *have* to use web forms (ASPX).  You can simply add an HTML page to your project using the add dialog.

Comment: hm? So I can creates WebForm, AJAX within my HTML file of my project? But then where did the code-behind goes? And isn't IIS understand that's script file by the extension?

Comment: If you don't need code behind, all you need is pure static HTML then there's no need to have the overhead of having an ASP page, ultimately all an aspx page contains is markup that the .NET runtime understands and then generate the HTML for you. For example an ASP label just writes out a span element into the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files ending with *.html* are optional. These are static HTML-pages without any code-behind and can be included as part of any web application. They are not parsed and compiled by the server but rather just sent as good old predefined HTML.

You can also configure the web server so that it routes requests with different endings through the ASP.net rendering engine. This way you can keep the widely recognized ending *.html* and still have dynamic page generation.

Comment: But the page I seen is to diplay client infromation dynamically... So shouldn't be static?

Answer (score 0):

The file extension is *not necessarily* tied to the execution engine. You can make ASP.NET process .aspx, .html, .htm, .bob, .foobar, .css, etc.

There are multiple of ways to do this:

1. In IIS manager, set the file extension mapping for .html to point to ASP.NET. If you're using MVC, you can handle this via routing.
2. Use a rewrite engine to map anything with a .htm* extension to .aspx

There are probably other ways, but these are the most direct.

Also, the .html extension doesn't mean that the file was dynamically generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL rewriting. There are a lot of different rewriters most popular being the URL rewrite module ( http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite ) and the built in (in ASP.NET 4.0) Routing Engine ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx ).

The URL Rewrite module is external to your application and it translates incoming URLs to regular .aspx URLs. You are responsible for generating the links with .html. It is good if you are adding it to an existing application.

The built in routing can generate urls based on routes and is configured in Global.asax (usually) with code.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project.
Add new...
pick the HTML file type.

Some people prefer to use a different extension (or even none at all) in order to hide the technology used to develop the site.

Bear in mind that you would have to properly configure IIS to let the .net engine handle the .html file types.